# Adding additional Python installations to 'py launcher'

Tags: python

I have four instances of Python installed on my machine, 2.7-32 & 3.7-32 that I installed manually into their default locations, and 2.7-64 & 3.4-64 that came as pre-packaged binaries with a statistical package that I need for work (SPSS). Py Launcher successfully detects the two installations that I installed manually but cannot see the two installations that came with the third party software.

I added the installation and Scripts directories of the two Python X-64 instances to the PATH variable and have confirmed that the change persists.

I've looked into creating a py.ini file and adding it to "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\" but haven't found a reference to how I can add additional installations using it.

I have added the two additional installation directories (and Scripts folders) to the PATH variable and confirmed that the changes persisted (displayed below):

```
PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\Scripts\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\;C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Program Files\IBM\SPSS\Statistics\24\Python\;C:\Program Files\IBM\SPSS\Statistics\24\Python\Scripts\;C:\Program Files\IBM\SPSS\Statistics\24\Python3\;C:\Program Files\IBM\SPSS\Statistics\24\Python3\Scripts\;
```

Current result of "py -0p" (List the available pythons with paths)

```
C:\>py -0p
Installed Pythons found by py Launcher for Windows
 -3.7-32        "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\python.exe" *
 -2.7-32        C:\Python27\python.exe
```

Expected result of "py -0p"

```
C:\>py -0p
Installed Pythons found by py Launcher for Windows
 -3.7-32        "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\python.exe" *
 -2.7-32        C:\Python27\python.exe
 -3.4-64        "C:\Program Files\IBM\SPSS\Statistics\24\Python3\python.exe"
 -2.7-64        "C:\Program Files\IBM\SPSS\Statistics\24\Python\python.exe"
```

Comment: Cross-post on Super User -- https://superuser.com/questions/1470907/adding-additional-python-installations-to-py-launcher

Comment: Cross-post on Python Issue Tracker: https://bugs.python.org/issue37856